# Entity не видят базу данных. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ошибка при попытке подсоединения

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

Делал REST приложение с использованием postgresql, docker'a и spring boot'a. Все работало отлично до тех пор, пока я не подключил докер и докер compose. Сама программа через докер работает: я отправляю get реквест на сервер и сервер отвечает из базы данных, которая находится в контейнере, но тесты не работают и так же мне подчеркивает все @Column, якобы база данных не подключена и ее нужно подключить, а при попытке запуска теста пишет "***org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ошибка при попытке подсоединения***". Базу данных конкретно в самой ide я не подключал(я имею ввиду плашку с боку, где написано Database), так как когда я работал с mongodb я ее там не подключал, когда работал с контейнером и все было нормально, никаких assign data source не выскакивало, а так же из-за того, что при попытке подключения выдает это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/schedule/")
public class ScheduleController {
    private final ScheduleServiceImpl scheduleServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    public ScheduleController(ScheduleServiceImpl scheduleServiceImpl){
        this.scheduleServiceImpl = scheduleServiceImpl;
    }

    @GetMapping("{studentId}")
    public String getSchedule(@PathVariable long studentId){
        return scheduleServiceImpl.findScheduleByStudentId(studentId);
    }
}
```

**group entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int groupId;

    @Column(name = "number_of_group")
    private String numberOfGroup;

    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "groups_timetable",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "timetable_id")
    )
    private List<Timetable> timetable;

    public Group(String numberOfGroup, List<Timetable> timetable){
        this.numberOfGroup = numberOfGroup;
        this.timetable = timetable;
    }
}
```

**student entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long studentId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "students_group",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    )
    private Group group;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, Group group){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.group = group;
    }
}
```

**timetable entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "timetable")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Timetable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long timetableId;

    private String schedule;

    @Column(name = "week_day")
    private int weekDay;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "timetable")
    private List<Group> group;

    public Timetable(String schedule, Integer weekDay){
        this.schedule = schedule;
        this.weekDay = weekDay;
    }
}
```

**properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://psql:5432/university_schedule

server.port=3033
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:16

ENV PORT 3033
EXPOSE $PORT

ARG DIR=build/libs/*.jar

COPY $DIR schedule.jar

ENTRYPOINT java -jar schedule.jar
```

**docker compose**

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  schedule-volume:

services:
  psql:
    container_name: postgres-container
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
      - POSTGRES_DB=university_schedule
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - schedule-volume:/data/db
  uni:
    container_name: schedule-container
    image: schedule
    ports:
      - 3033:3033
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://psql:5432/university_schedule
    links:
      - postgresql
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы пытаетесь подключиться к бд по хосту "psql", который резолвится только внутри сети докер.
Попробуйте "localhost" вместо "psql" на первом скрине (при условии что докер поднят локально).

Если докер не на локалке - попробуйте подключиться по ip машины (прошу заметить, он может измениться в будущем).

Получить ip машины:

```
linux 
   ip -a
win 
   ipconfig
```

ссылка на описание network для docker-compose
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: у меня все на локальном, проблема заключается в том, что у меня на localhost'е другие данные в бд, не такие, как в контейнере в докере на порте psql

Comment: я конечно могу копировать данные из контейнера в базу данных на локальном хосте, но будет ли это корректно? Я думал, что если уже у меня есть докер контейнер программы, то все должно работать на хосте контейнера, а не что-то на psql, а что-то на localhost

Comment: погодите, в вашем compose файле для postgres прокидывается наружу порт 5432. 
При подключении через localhost:5432 вы должны подключаться к бд, развёрнутой в контейнере. Я не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете в виду под "у меня на localhost'е другие данные в бд"

Comment: извиняюсь, возможно не очень корректно выразился. Сейчас я подключил базу данных в левой вкладке "Database", но все равно сохранилась ошибка "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ошибка при попытке подсоединения" при запуске теста. Все как вы и говорили: вместо psql написать localhost

Comment: а вы поменяли properties для подключения
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://psql:5432/university_schedule
на 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/university_schedule ?

Comment: не поменял) Теперь все работает, спасибо!

Comment: рекомендую ещё погуглить на тему spring profiles, возможно это то, что даст ответ на удалённый вами комментарий
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#2-profile-specific-properties-files